# Help with Date Conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Can someone tell me how to convert it to: January 1, 2011?

Comment: Do you want it in English only or in locale-specific language?

Comment: Also, possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript

Comment: -1 Your question doesn't show any research effort at all! What have you tried, and what are the complications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "01/01/2011",
date = new Date(str),
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
converted = months[date.getMonth()] + " " + 
            date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
```

[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ayidic/4/edit#javascript).

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already, check out date.js -

http://www.datejs.com/

It's great for any date related functions, and has tons of examples on their site to do everything you can imagine.

**Update:** Ok some people doubt my mad coding skillz :)

```
<script src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="Javascript">
  var d = Date.parse('03/08/1980'); 
  window.alert(d.toString('MMMM d, yyyy'));
</script>
```

Comment: Even though there's no code in the answer, +1 for a useful resource that I didn't know about!

Comment: If you recommend a library to do this, you should at least show how to do what the person is asking for. I'll rescind my downvote if you edit to show how to do this with date.js.

Comment: DateJS is not that great of a library, it seriously messes with the Native Date prototype. It adds over 20 properties to the `Date` object, and over 90 methods to the `Date.prototype`, including overriding `.toString`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1/1/2011";

var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];    
var parts = str.split("/");
var formatted = monthNames[parseInt(parts[0], 10)-1] + " " + parts[1] + ", " + parts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
var dat = new Date("01/01/2011");
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var stringDate = monthNames[dat.getMonth()] + ", " + dat.getDate() + ", " + dat.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a date library similar to DateJS, only it's smaller, faster, and doesn't modify the `Date.prototype`. It handles parsing, manipulating, and formatting, including timeago.

I see that you only need english, but there is support for i18n in underscore.date.

https://github.com/timrwood/underscore.date

With underscore.date, this is how you would solve your problem.

```
_date('01/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MMMM D, YYYY');
```

Comment: So `MMMM` returns the name of the month?

Comment: Correct, MMMM = full name of month, MMM = abbreviated name of the month. All the replacement keys are in the docs at https://github.com/timrwood/underscore.date