# Convert a yyyy-mm-dd to other date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to convert "1983-24-12" to December 24, 1983 using Javascript.

Do we have any ready made function in Javascript which makes this conversion same as `simpledateformat` in Java?

I am trying to avoid taking months in Arrays and then do the manipulation.

My Code is as below.

```
//For Date Format
    months = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",           "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];     
    dob = responseObj.data.personDetail.birthDate.split('-');   
    month = months[dob[1]];
    responseObj.data.personDetail.birthDate = month +" "+dob[2] +","+dob[0];
```

Kindly help.

Comment: There is a *Date.prototype.toLocaleString* method, but then you'd first have to convert the string to a date (not hard, but needs 2 or 3 lines of code) and then a call to *toLocaleString*. And then the method is implementation dependent so you get whatever the browser returns, which is different in just about every browser. Many also ignore local settings so return the US-centric month, day, year even if the system settings are for day, moth, year. So the method you are using is already probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Since you mentioned that you're using Sencha, you can use [`Ext.Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date) to add advanced date formatting and parsing:

> A set of useful static methods to deal with date Note that if Ext.Date is required and loaded, it will copy all methods / properties to this object for convenience.

You can find more information here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date

The two methods you might find useful are [parse](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-parse) and [format](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-format)

---

Alternatively, JQuery UI's [DatePicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) widget implements a very robust date parser and formatter, which can be used in your own code like this:

```
var parsedDate = $.DatePicker.parseDate("yy-m-d", "1983-24-12");
var outputString = $.DatePicker.formatDate("MM d, yy", parsedDate);
// outputString = "December 24, 1983"
```

The relevant functions here are [parseDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) and [formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).

There is one problem though, to use this you'll have to include both JQuery and JQuery UI as scripts in your code, which is probably a little excessive for what you need, and the other answers may perhaps suit your needs better.

Comment: @HPK - I've edited my answer, I've added a bit about using Sencha Ext JS that might work for you :-)

Comment: I have used birthDate = date.dateFormat( "F d, Y" ); // Sencha DateObject. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use a library why not just split the date string and concoct your own date?

```
var str_date = "1983-24-12",
    arr_date = str_date.split('-'),
    months   = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

alert(months[arr_date[2]] + ' ' + arr_date[1] + ', ' + arr_date[0]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9xeBZ/

JavaScript has the `Date()` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

The problem is that the JavaScript `Date()` object will not return a string representation of a month. So at some point you will have to create that logic yourself. Also the format you posted ("1983-24-12") is an invalid format for parsing with the `Date()` object.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I tried the same but trying to avoid taking the help from array. DO we have any simpledateformat kind of formatter function which helps us in this case? I am making a mobile website with Sencha framework

Comment: @HPK I updated my answer with the paragraph at the end. Also here is a link to a SO answer that shows how to add this functionality to your site via `Date.prototype`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1643506/752738

Comment: BTW, *Date.prototype.toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, some browsers do return the full month name (e.g. Safari) and some don't.

Answer (score 2):

This might help: [Date Format Conversion](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Comment: I am avoiding to try to put any library in my code which will unnecessary increase the size of my mobile website. I am trying if sencha provides any help..

Comment: Then could you show some of your codes... what have you tried..?

Comment: @HPK–if you are concerned about the size of your code, why on earth are you using bloatware like Sencha?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you are trying to reformat your date for which a quick google search brought up this http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format which looks like what you want.