# How to change 24hr time to 12hr time with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON Scraping - Convert military time to standard time via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658097/json-scraping-convert-military-time-to-standard-time-via-javascript)

My input is e.g.

0400

0915

1200

1615

0015

I need to convert them to e.g

04:00am

09:15am

12:00pm

04:15pm

00:15am

Is there any scripts available that I can make use of?

Comment: `if (time > 1259) time = time - 1200`

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var getFormattedTime = function (fourDigitTime){
    var hours24 = parseInt(fourDigitTime.substring(0,2));
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = fourDigitTime.substring(2);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + amPm;
};
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/RMnfA/) to test it.

Comment: I cracked my brain to think of a solution to try replacing time direct from HTML using the replace solution I found from other thread. $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/1800/g,6:00pm));

Comment: Should I start a new thread for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Date`? I'm pretty sure it can do this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

They are plenty of librairies to handle dates and times, you can use [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The below script give the output you except...

Try it....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dtval = "0915"; //Time in 24hrs

 alert(fomartTimeShow(dtval[0] + dtval[1],dtval[2] + dtval[3]));

 function fomartTimeShow(h_24,h_min) {
     var h = h_24 % 12;
     if (h === 0) h = 12;
     return (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + h_min + (h_24 < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
}
</script>
```

Comment: The output was });//]]> , not sure where went wrong..