# Formatting getDate() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getdate

I have been playing around with this JavaScript to get the right format on my date output, but with no luck. I need this code to show as Month Day, Year. As of now it's showing dd/mm/yy.

Below is the script I'm using.

```
<script>
var tD = new Date();
var datestr = tD.getDate() + (tD.getMonth()+ 1)  + ", " + tD.getFullYear();
document.write("<input type='hidden' name='date' value='"+datestr+"'>");
</script>
```

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods) for reference on all `Date` object methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modification of [another post here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/1721527). I think this will do what you want.

```
var tD = new Date();
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var datestr = monthNames[tD.getMonth()] + " " + tD.getDate()  + ", " + tD.getFullYear();
document.write("<input type='hidden' name='date' value='"+datestr+"'>");
```

Comment: Why not just link to the post? :)

Comment: @Robin Because that post doesn't do exactly what the OP wanted. I wanted to be more helpful by giving him exactly the code he should use, and because link-only posts are discouraged even if there just links to other posts. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers.

Comment: freaking awesome this worked perfectly. thats why you guys are the experts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get it. Is this, what you're looking for?

```
<script>
var tD = new Date();
var datestr = (tD.getMonth() + 1) + ' ' + tD.getDay() + ", " + tD.getFullYear();
document.write("<input type='hidden' name='date' value='"+datestr+"'>");
</script>
```