# Is there a snippet for javascript switch statement for all the months

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, switch-statement

I'm trying to display  a tabbed pane with the current month. Using Bootstrap's tab method. Wondering if anyone sees any flaws in this code? So far It's working how I want, use and test yourself.

**The HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="monthsTab">
   <li><a href="#January" id="janLink" data-toggle="tab">January</a></li>
   <li><a href="#February" id="febLink" data-toggle="tab" >February</a></li>
   <li><a href="#March" id="marLink" data-toggle="tab">March</a></li>
   <li><a href="#April" id="aprLink" data-toggle="tab">April</a></li>
   <li><a href="#May" id="mayLink" data-toggle="tab">May</a></li>
   <li><a href="#June" id="junLink" data-toggle="tab">June</a></li>
   <li><a href="#July" id="julLink" data-toggle="tab">July</a></li>
   <li><a href="#August" id="augLink" data-toggle="tab">August</a></li>
   <li><a href="#September" id="sepLink" data-toggle="tab">September</a></li>
   <li><a href="#October" id="octLink" data-toggle="tab">October</a></li>
   <li><a href="#November" id="novLink" data-toggle="tab">November</a></li>
   <li><a href="#December" id="decLink" data-toggle="tab">December</a></li>
</ul>
```

**And the JS:**

```
var currentMonth = function () {
        var myMonth=new Date();
        var theMonth = myMonth.getMonth();
        var target = '';
        var month = '';
        switch (theMonth) {
         case 0:
            target = "janLink";
            month = "January";
         break;
         case 1:
            target = "febLink";
            month = "February";
         break;
         case 2:
            target = "marLink";
            month = "March";
         break;
         case 3:
            target = "aprLink";
            month = "April";
         break;
         case 4:
            target = "mayLink";
            month = "May";
         break;
         case 5:
            target = "junLink";
            month = "June";
         break;
         case 6:
            target = "julLink";
            month = "July";
         break;
         case 7:
            target = "augLink";
            month = "August";
         break;
         case 8:
            target = "sepLink";
            month = "September";
         break;
         case 9:
            target = "octLink";
            month = "October";
         break;
         case 10:
            target = "novLink";
            month = "November";
         break;
         case 11:
            target = "decLink";
            month = "December";
         break;
        }
        $('#monthsTab, ' + '#' + target).parent().addClass('active');
        $('#'+month).addClass('active');
    };
    currentMonth();
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the appropriate place to post code that isn't broken.

Comment: You could use an array instead of this huge switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1643320/901048

Comment: @Blazemonger ehhh not fully. But it should go to code review probably.

Comment: didn't know about code review, I should add that I'm wondering what's best for performance here?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that loooooooooooong switch case I would use an array of objects:

```
var months = [
   {name: "January" , link: "janLink"}, 
   {name: "February" , link: "febLink"}, 
   ...
];

var currentMonth = function () {
    var myMonth = new Date();
    var theMonth = myMonth.getMonth();
    $('#monthsTab, #' + months[theMonth].link).parent().addClass('active');
    $('#' + months[theMonth].name).addClass('active');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To show also a proper content you should trigger a click event on a choosen tab.
You wrote quite o long code for such a task - as long as tabs are in order you can determine which tab to activate by order (look at [jQuery.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/))

```
$('#monthsTab li').eq(myMonth.getMonth()).trigger('click');
```

Comment: The idea is to display the proper content for whatever month it is on  pageload so the user doesn't have to select the current month, but can still go back and forth between months.

Comment: What I meant is that adding "active" class affects only a look of a tab. It doesn't activate a proper `.tab-pane` element. Thats why I proposed triggering a click event.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap has a proper API for this : `.tab('show')`