# Javascript date object native code to get month name?

Tags: javascript, date

I Have seen quite a lot of solutions for getting the month name of a [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in JavaScript, mostly using an array or object of month names and matching them to the value of Date.getMonth() or Date.getUTCMonth().

Here is one of the more popular [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript).

Whilst this approach works fine, I am wondering if I can get the name straight from the date object itself. We already have various versions of ['toString'](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybrooks/qj78S/) which all provide a month name as part of their return string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="tostring"></div>
    <div id="todatestring"></div>
    <div id="toutcdatestring"></div>
    <script>
        var a = new Date();
        document.getElementById("tostring").innerHTML = a.toString();
        document.getElementById("todatestring").innerHTML = a.toDateString();
        document.getElementById("toutcdatestring").innerHTML = a.toUTCString();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So why cant we get the month name straight from a date object, or at least get access to what ever mechanism date has for mapping names to months?

Comment: Heh, I get the feeling that if this was possible, all of the examples you've come across would have used it, rather then defining their own arrays ;).

Comment: The trivial answer for why you can't "get the month name straight from a date object" because ECMA-262 doesn't include a "getMonthAsString" method, but you can easily add one. Note that you will need to take account of different language settings.

Answer (score 0):

The month names you get from `.toUTCString()` are 3-letter names, so: Jan, Feb, Apr etc.

I think that's the best you can do. Having a list of month names isn't so odd. It's not too inconvenient, month names don't change all that often after all ;)

Comment: The value returned by [*toUTCString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.42) is implementation dependent and does not necessarily contain a month name. The [recommended format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) is a version of ISO8601 and does not use month names.