# how to convert date format from 10/04/2013 to Oct 4,2013

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my date 10/04/2013 i convert it oct 4,2013.

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="dateofissue" id="dateofissue" readonly>
```

and here is javascript who get current date:

```
var now = new Date();
 document.getElementById("dateofissue").value=(now.getMonth()+1)+'/'+now.getDate()+'/'+now.getFullYear();
```

it shows date in format 10/04/2013.i want when it shows date in this format i get this date and converrt it in oct 4,2013

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/uCGk8/36/)

Comment: you have to declare an array of month like the one mentioned in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript)

Comment: or something like `toDateString()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var now = new Date();
var monthNamesL = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
    monthNamesS = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];

var dateFmtd = monthNamesS[now.getMonth()] + ' ' + now.getDay() + ', ' + now.getFullYear();

document.getElementById("dateofissue").value = dateFmtd;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/3VqAK/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var datestring = d1.toDateString().substring(4).split(' ');
var datestr = datestring[0]+' '+parseInt(datestring[1])+', '+datestring[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
var d1 = new Date();
var datestring = d1.toDateString().substring(4).split(' ').join(',').replace(',',' ').replace('0','');
alert(datestring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var now =new Date().toDateString();
var date = now.split(' ');
var formattedDate=date[1]+" "+parseInt(date[2])+","+date[3];
document.getElementById("dateofissue").value=formattedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It also has a host of other useful features.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use external library then I would prefer to use

### [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format("MMM, D YYYY");  //Oct 4,2013
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the format you need

```
var now = new Date();
$.datepicker.formatDate("M d,yy", now);
```