# How can I get the current month name in capitals with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the name of the month in JavaScript in capitals.

I know I can use the `getMonth()` method to get the current month and use the number to extract the month name in capitals from an array, but is there a built-in method to do the same?

Comment: `var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

document.write("The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()]);`  Of course you can capalize the months in the array or use the toUpperCase function.  (I know uses an array but its simple)

Comment: How's this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript -- From the bottom post: http://jsfiddle.net/dstorey/Xgerq/

Comment: 'but is there a built-in method to do the same'... simple answer, no. while the syntax itself is en-us, the language is culture agnostic. btw agree with Barmar... moment.js is the way to go if you want to power up JS dates.

Comment: @JamesGaunt maybe JavaScript doesn't have a method built-in, but there has to be a lib out there that does.

Comment: Try moment.js, it's the canonical library for date/time-related needs.

Comment: @Mr Jones... indeed. but that wouldn't be 'built in' would it?  if you can't be bothered to type up a 100 character array why would you include an entire library?

Comment: @JamesGaunt because it only takes one line of code to include a library

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FtoDateString

Comment: I especially like moment.js because it supports localization. An array-based method supporting more than English would be a less trivial exercise.

Comment: An easy solution would be to use css -> text-transform: capitalize;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, see [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

While this method has been around for quite some time, it is only recently that browsers have begun to implement the `locales` and `options` arguments and is therefore not yet widely [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_Compatibility).

Javascript

```
var today = new Date(),
    options = {
        month: "long"
    },
    month = today.toLocaleString("en-GB", options).toUpperCase();

alert(month);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/mQEe3/)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider the JavaScript Date object's function [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FtoLocaleString).  You can specify the locale and format to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have a method built in to retrieve the name of the month. You will have to create a method of your own, nearly all of which will use some form of fetching an entry from an `Array` of month names.

Comment: The JavaScript Date object does have a series of "to...String()" functions that include the month name, but the way the string is returned for these functions is implementation dependent and may vary by locale as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d=new Date();
var month=['January' , 'February' ,'March', 'April' , 'May' ,'June', 'July' , 'August' ,'September', 'October' , 'November' ,'December'];
var n = month[d.getMonth()];
alert(n);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer not to use an array literal: `month = ['January', 'February', 'March' /*...*/];`? (incidentally, not my down-vote; I'm just curious.)

Comment: OP asked for an alternative method.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a simpler way of doing this, that's all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are content with the 3 letter month abbreviation this would work:

```
d.toDateString().substr(4,3).toUpperCase()
```

Full disclaimer: I'm not sure if that would be affected by the region or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
const today = new Date();
const options = {month: 'long'};

today.toLocaleDateString('it-IT', options);
```

A way for getting the month from a Date Object.