# SQL format DATETIME to count months

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, chart.js

I'm wanting to get all the datetime column in my db but but it in a graph using Chart.js, now hard coding data in works fine but I want to know i can use my db datetime col to count how many sign ups happened is each month then return this to the graph, anyone know how to do this?

Currently when someone signs up it enters the date like:
2013-12-18 12:03:50

So I need to grab the months then post this to the graph :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use MySQL `MONTH()` function, like:

`SELECT MONTH(table.date) from table WHERE ...`

In case you want to count the amount by month, so use the count function and group the query by `MONTH(datetime)`. If you need help with this, please leave a comment.

For example, if you have a table that has a list of users, it will look something like that:

`SELECT YEAR(register_date), MONTH(register_date) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS registered FROM users GROUP BY YEAR(register_date), MONTH(register_date)` - this will give you the result of registered users count by year and month.

Comment: Will that count the months, or will i need to include count()

Comment: This last col is what i need:http://d.pr/i/OiUs  signup_date which has type of datetime

Comment: I called it `register_date`, just use the other name.

Comment: I just want it to then display in the chart like this hard coded version http://d.pr/i/dIOK

Comment: Then the question you are asking in the top is a different one. Here is an example for the chart with some code - http://www.arcadiacharts.com/create_JS_chart

Comment: using the example you gave and i called it with a set $var in json_encode format i get

[{"YEAR(signup_date)":2013,"MONTH":6,"registered":10},{"YEAR(signup_date)":2013,"MONTH":7,"registered":3},{"YEAR(signup_date)":2013,"MONTH":11,"registered":2},{"YEAR(signup_date)":2013,"MONTH":12,"registered":9}] 

Which is great but now how do i order those to go in the correct months based on my graph format like so : http://paste.laravel.com/1ffI

Comment: You need to create a map of month names to month numbers in order to match the query return result. There is a bunch of solutions over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript