# Javascript Date Conversion milliseconds to month, date, year

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to convert milliseconds into a date that looks like: `Oct 04, 2013`. I converted milliseconds into a date object with:

```
var d1 = new Date(milliseconds);
```

which then outputs something like:

```
Fri Oct 04 2013 13:59:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

If I use `getMonth()` , `getDate()`, and `getFullYear()` the output becomes `9 4 2013`

How do I get the month either a full name (October) or shortened to three characters (Oct)?

Comment: [get month names from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Comment: Either create your own lookup table or find a date library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It provides all date conversions that you could possibly need.

With Moment.js, you would do this:

```
moment(milliseconds).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
```

Here is a full format table for use with moment objects: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use a library, one solution to showing 'written' months would be to create an array containing all month names:

```
var monthName = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```

From there, you can use this array to display the month name in a string:

```
var d1 = new Date(milliseconds),
    d = d1.getDate(),
    m = d1.getMonth(),
    y = d1.getFullYear();

var dateString = monthName[m] + " " + d + " " + y; // Oct 4 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

Months in javascript start at zero so getMonth() on a February date will return 1 for example.

Answer (score 1):

The best choice would be `d1.toDateString()`.
Other than that there is no StringFormat for Dates in JavaScript.