# Looking to add 1 month to current date inside a div

Tags: javascript, date, dynamic

i am looking to display the date plus 1 month inside a div which will be used to display next invoice date. i have seen a few examples in various places, but could not implement. I also saw that there were many solutions, and some controversy surrounding each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use this : http://jsfiddle.net/dfA8b/ if you need same date of the next month

```
var invoiceDt = new Date();
invoiceDt.setMonth(invoiceDt.getMonth()+1);
$('#invoiceDate').text(invoiceDt.toDateString());
```

Or

You can use this : http://jsfiddle.net/hjSDu/ if you need 30 days month(mostly used for invoice purposes)

```
var invoiceDt = new Date();
var days = 30;
invoiceDt.setDate(invoiceDt.getDate()+days);
$('#invoiceDate').text(invoiceDt.toDateString());
```

For the formatting purpose :
http://jsfiddle.net/7bU6n/

```
var invoiceDt = new Date();
invoiceDt.setMonth(invoiceDt.getMonth()+1);
$('#invoiceDate').text((invoiceDt.getMonth()+1) +"-"+ invoiceDt.getDate() +"-" + invoiceDt.getFullYear());
```

also see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/3603806

Comment: is there a simple way to remove the actual day and only leave the month, day and year?

Comment: @user3723502 I've added the formatting part in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a date object, just call **setMonth()**, passing in the current number of months plus 1.

```
var CurrentDate = new Date();
CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 month is not so clear... what You mean? 31, 30 days or if exists simply same date of the following month?

1st case: (assuming 31 days)

```
var d = new Date(),
    dplus31 = d.getDate() + 31;
d.setDate(dplus31);
console.debug(d, dplus31);
```

2nd case: one month

```
var d = new Date(),
    dplus1 = d.getMonth() + 1;
d.setMonth(dplus1);
console.debug(d, dplus1);
```

..but even in this case there are some edge cases (ex. 31 January)
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
function addMonthsNoOverflow(dateParam, intParam) {
    var sum = new Date(new Date(dateParam.getTime()).setMonth(dateParam.getMonth() + intParam);
    if (sum.getDate() < dateParam.getDate()) {  sum.setDate(0);  }
    return(sum);
}
```

Notes:
It handles cases where 29, 30 or 31 turned into 1, 2, or 3 by eliminating the overflow
Day of Month is NOT zero-indexed so .setDate(0) is last day of prior month.