# Coverting DATETIME string to time and date in words Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

i have a datetime parameter in a string from an JSON object

like this-

```
        datetime:"2015-04-15 09.00.00"
```

my goal is to convert it to:

```
        "15 April 09:00"
```

(2015 can be included as well but not necessary)
After i will append in in 2 different places, date and time.

Any suggestions? Can't seem to find any good info apart from getting a plugin.

Comment: I use moment for this kind of stuff, it supports almost everything I throw at it. 
http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the month like the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/2498251

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
```

so for your case you can make something like this:

```
var d = new Date("2015-04-15 09:00:00");
var day = d.getDay();
var month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
var year = d.getYear();
var hour = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();

var fullDatetime = day + ' ' + month + ' ' + hour + ':' + min;
```

Comment: running your example var day gets the value 3.