# Javascript Clock not showing up

Tags: javascript, clock

So I have a HTML website (not actually online) and I'm just messing around with it. Recently I added a clock, however, after doing a lot of editing with it, there seems to be an error that I can't find. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function updateTime() { var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June
function updateTime() {
var currentTime = new Date();
var dayWk = currentTime.getDay();
var year = currentTime.getYear() - 100 + 2000;
var month = monthNames[currentTime.getMonth()];
var date = currentTime.getDate();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var dayWkNm = " ";
var dateFuncVar = date;
var dateSuffix = " ";
if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (seconds < 10){
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
if (dayWk == 0){
    dayWkNm = "Sunday";
}
if (dayWk == 1){
    dayWkNm = "Monday";
}
if (dayWk == 2){
    dayWkNm = "Tuesday";
}
if (dayWk == 3){
    dayWkNm = "Wednesday";
}
if (dayWk == 4){
    dayWkNm = "Thursday";
}
if (dayWk == 5){
    dayWkNm = "Friday";
}
if (dayWk == 6){
    dayWkNm = "Saturday";
}
function dateFunc(dateFuncVar) {
    while (dateFuncVar > 9) {
        dateFuncVar = dateFuncVar - 10;
    }

    if (dateFuncVar == 1){
        dateSuffix = "st";
    } else if (dateFuncVar == 2){
        dateSuffix = "nd";
    } else if (dateFuncVar == 3){
        dateSuffix = "rd";
    } else {
        dateSuffix = "th";
    }
    return dateFuncVar;
}
var text = dayWkNm + "the" + date + " of " + month + ", " + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
if(hours > 11){
    text+=" PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
} else {
    text+=" AM";
}

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=text;
}

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
//-->
</script>
<head>
<title>
Welcome to the Goto home page
</title>
<h3>
<p style="text-align:right" id="time">
</p>
</h3>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for the error reports?

Comment: I am not using a browser, but rather an app on my iPad to type up the code. It doesn't submit error reports

Comment: Typos in your else ifs. `elseif ` should be `else if`. Also, where do you define the function `getMonthName`?

Comment: getMonthName I confused with [MIT App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu). I'll change the else ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/PtlbPQQHT3wIzDIafaN7?p=preview

There were a few errors:

1. It should be "else if" not "elseif"
2. You were returning dateFuncVar too soon
3. getMonthName is not a function, so I replaced it with the answer from [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date) (go upvote that question and answer, too, if you accept this answer)
4. Not an error, but I would use setInterval instead of redoing a setTimeout inside the function.

   function updateTime() {
             var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
           ];

   ```
       var currentTime = new Date();
       var dayWk = currentTime.getDay();
       var year = currentTime.getYear() - 100 + 2000;
       var month = monthNames[currentTime.getMonth()];
       var date = currentTime.getDate();
       var hours = currentTime.getHours();
       var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
       var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
       var dayWkNm = " ";
       var dateFuncVar = date;
       var dateSuffix = " ";
       if (minutes < 10){
           minutes = "0" + minutes;
       }
       if (seconds < 10){
           seconds = "0" + seconds;
       }
       if (dayWk == 0){
           dayWkNm = "Sunday";
       }
       if (dayWk == 1){
           dayWkNm = "Monday";
       }
       if (dayWk == 2){
           dayWkNm = "Tuesday";
       }
       if (dayWk == 3){
           dayWkNm = "Wednesday";
       }
       if (dayWk == 4){
           dayWkNm = "Thursday";
       }
       if (dayWk == 5){
           dayWkNm = "Friday";
       }
       if (dayWk == 6){
           dayWkNm = "Saturday";
       }
       function dateFunc(dateFuncVar) {
           while (dateFuncVar > 9) {
               dateFuncVar = dateFuncVar - 10;
           }

           if (dateFuncVar == 1){
               dateSuffix = "st";
           } else if (dateFuncVar == 2){
               dateSuffix = "nd";
           } else if (dateFuncVar == 3){
               dateSuffix = "rd";
           } else {
               dateSuffix = "th";
           }
           return dateFuncVar;
       }
       var text = dayWkNm + "the" + date + " of " + month + ", " + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
       if(hours > 11){
           text+=" PM";
           hours = hours - 12;
       } else {
           text+=" AM";
       }

       document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=text;
   }

   setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
   ```

Comment: Thanks. However, the clock still doesn't want to show up.

Comment: Lol then why did you accept this as the correct answer? Anyways, you're sure you have a div/span/etc.. with the id of "time"? This exact code works in the plnkr.

Comment: I changed the post so now it has the html up to the point where the clock is used

Comment: You're just missing monthNames. It got cut off from the "code" and I gave up trying to format it in my answer lol. Add this to the very beginning of your function: var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

Comment: No problem! What app are you using on your iPad? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Code Master. It's not the best, but it does support a good amount of codes

Answer (score 0):

Look at where you are returning "dateFuncVar".  I am willing to bet the rest of your code is not getting executed.