# How to extract only the months from the datepicker widget in Kendo UI to an alertbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, in my view I am using Kendo UI. I want to display only the month and year from the Datepicker widget(Example: JANUARY 2016) into the alertbox, but instead I am getting the following:[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GetoI.png)

My view code is as follows:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
               .Name("datepicker")
               .Start(CalendarView.Year)
               .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
               .Format("MMMM yyyy")
               .Value(DateTime.Today)
               .HtmlAttributes(new { style = " width: 95.5%;})
               .Events(e => e.Change("monthpicker_change"))

    )

<script>
   // monthpicker_change function
    function monthpicker_change() {

      var month = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
     alert(month.value());

   }
</script>
```

Please suggest me what changes I need to do in my script, in order to display only the selected Month and Year in an Alert box.

PS: I have formatted the datepicker to display only the MONTHS and YEAR, not the standard dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kendoDatePicker.value` method always return javascript `Date`.

You should use `Date` methods to extract month and year from date object:

```
var date = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
alert((date.getMonth()+1) + '.' + date.getFullYear());
```

Beware: getMonth() return values from 0 to 11; 0 is january.

Here is full reference of `Date` functions: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: thank you.It works really well, but is there any method to return the Months as string like(January, February)?

Comment: @Alchemist check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date

Comment: Thanks a lot, instead of array I used a switch. But using an array looks more clean. I will replace the same with array.