# Ember Date get Month, Year, and Day

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've searched around but I couldn't find any help.

I want to know if I can get the Day, Month, and Year, and maybe other attributes, from Ember's Date attribute.

For example, in one of my models, I have something like this:

```
createdAt: DS.attr('string', {
    defaultValue() {
        return new Date();
    }
})
```

which returns me this format: Tue Feb 23 2016 10:27:10 GMT-0800 (PST)

Is there a way which I can get the "Feb" portion from the whole Date?

I know in pure JS, you can do something like var today = new Date.getMonth(), but that doesn't work, of course, for Ember's date.

Thank you.

Comment: Just split the `Date()` as a string and return the second item in the array.

Comment: var values = this.get('createdAt').split(' ');
  var mm = values[1];
  return mm;    this code returns me a blank in ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Your can make it work using `new Date.getMonth()` as You said in your question. See the following code:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
   createdAt: DS.attr('string', {
        defaultValue() {
            return new Date();
        }
    }),
    createdMonth: Ember.computed('createdAt', function(){ 
        return this.get('createdAt').getMonth() + 1 // returns 2 for the current month (February)
    })
});
```

The next thing You might do is choose a way of converting the number to a month name. Please check this: [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much! One question is, did Ember Docs list functions like that ('getMonth, getYear..., getDate) on their website? Or do we just use whatever Javascript has?

Comment: I think we just use whatever Javascript has, because `Date` is comming from JS, not ember.

Comment: Ah okay, have you ever gotten this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).getMonth is not a function"? On my website, the data displays once but if I go to another page and go back to it, it disappears.