# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd formatted date to 'long date' format using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have date in yyyy-mm-dd format. It is found to be ISO Date format. I need to convert it to Long Date format.

eg: I have date as '2015-07-15'. The converted date format should be in 15 July 2015.

I went through several methods. But didn't get the expected result. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: If you have a serious level project and need date manipulations in many pages, I suggest using well known date libraries or UI components to provide a stable support to your project. Like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), [kendoUI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepickers), etc...

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library for this purpose:

```js
console.log(moment("2015-07-15").format("DD MMMM YYYY")); //prints 15 July 2015
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var current_date = new Date("2015-07-15");
month_value = current_date.getMonth();
day_value = current_date.getDate();
year_value = current_date.getFullYear();

document.write("Converted date is : " + 
day_value +" "+ months[month_value] + " " + year_value);
```

Check discussion and many other solution here : [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Answer (score 0):

```
var months=["jan","feb","march","April","may","jun","july","August","sept","oct","nov","dec"];
var dateValue=new Date();
var date=dateValue.getDate();
var year=dateValue.getFullYear()
console.log("Today is :"+date+ "  "+months[dateValue.getMonth()]+"   "+year);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using switch,

```
function getFormattedDate(input){
    date = new Date(''+input+'T00:00:00Z');
    var y=date.getFullYear();
        var m=date.getMonth()+1;
        var d=date.getDate();
        var mmm="";
        switch(m)
        {
         case 1:
          mmm="Jan";
            break;
            case 2:
          mmm="Feb";
            break;
            case 3:
          mmm="Mar";
            break;
            case 4:
          mmm="Apr";
            break;
            case 5:
          mmm="May";
            break;
            case 6:
          mmm="June";
            break;
            case 7:
          mmm="July";
            break;
            case 8:
          mmm="Aug";
            break;
            case 9:
          mmm="Sept";
            break;
            case 10:
          mmm="Oct";
            break;
            case 11:
          mmm="Nov";
            break;
            case 12:
          mmm="Dec";
            break;
        }

        alert(d+' '+mmm+' '+y)
}

getFormattedDate("2015-07-15");
```

Working [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/Law8czoc/)