# Change number on month

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

i want to change the numbers on words in front.

Ex : 0 = January / 1 = February / 2 = March....

This is my code HTML

```
<div class="input-group btn-group select-date">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i></button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="05" min="01" max="12" readonly>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

This is my code JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.select-date .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
      var btn = $(this);
      var input = btn.closest('.select-date').find('input');
      if (input.attr('max') == undefined || parseInt(input.val()) < parseInt(input.attr('max'))) {    
        input.val(parseInt(input.val(), 10) + 1);
      } else {
        btn.next("disabled", true);
      }
    });
    $('.select-date .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
      var btn = $(this);
      var input = btn.closest('.select-date').find('input');
      if (input.attr('min') == undefined || parseInt(input.val()) > parseInt(input.attr('min'))) {    
        input.val(parseInt(input.val(), 10) - 1);
      } else {
        btn.prev("disabled", true);
      }
    });
})
```

Please can you help me to solved the problem, i'm really lost.

[image: I won't the number but the mont]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get month name from Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Comment: Can you create a JS fiddle?

Comment: This is the link of the test http://pier17.fr/beta-test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to keep as close as possible to your original code. I also assumed that you need the month names in French.

The idea is to store the month number as an attribute of your `<input>`, just like you did for 'min' and 'max' and to set the input value to the month name on each change.

Because `toLocaleString` is not supported on every browser, you may want to hardcode this array instead: `var monthName = [ 'janvier', 'février', etc. ];`.

Aside: `new Date(0, n + 1)` is generating a date in the year 1900. But that's OK for what we're doing here.

```js
var monthName = [];

for(var n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
  monthName[n] = (new Date(0, n + 1)).toLocaleString('fr-FR', { month: "long" });
}

$(function(){
    $('.select-date .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {
      var btn = $(this);
      var input = btn.closest('.select-date').find('input');
      if (input.attr('max') == undefined || parseInt(input.attr('month')) < parseInt(input.attr('max'))) {    
        input.attr('month', parseInt(input.attr('month'), 10) + 1);
        input.val(monthName[parseInt(input.attr('month'), 10) - 1]);
      } else {
        btn.next("disabled", true);
      }
    });
    $('.select-date .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {
      var btn = $(this);
      var input = btn.closest('.select-date').find('input');
      if (input.attr('min') == undefined || parseInt(input.attr('month')) > parseInt(input.attr('min'))) {    
        input.attr('month', parseInt(input.attr('month'), 10) - 1);
        input.val(monthName[parseInt(input.attr('month'), 10) - 1]);
      } else {
        btn.prev("disabled", true);
      }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group btn-group select-date">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>-</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="mai" month="5" min="1" max="12" readonly>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please note that I've slightly updated my answer, so that `monthName` is a zero-based array. (Just to be consistent with my remark about hardcoding it, if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Create class:

```
var Months=function(){

this.months=[
 "January"
 ... //all months
 ];

};

Months.prototype.getMonthName=function(num){

 if (num<0 || num>11){

   console.log("no such month!");
   return null;
 }


 return this.months[num];
};
```

example usage:

```
var months=new Months();
months.getMonthName(0); //January
```