# JavaScript date in dd/MMM/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can show date in this format dd/MMM/yyyy using below code

```
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
    debugger;
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    debugger;
    return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt.getDate() + "-" + dt.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: `MMM` = 3 letters of month?

Comment: You ok with jquery-ui? Or only jquery?

Comment: What exactly is `value` that you send to the function? Give some examples...

Comment: date is shown in this format 590104800000

Comment: so i use this method to convert it

Comment: JavaScript is not "Java script"

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

...

return dt.getDate() + "/" + monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
```

Other ideas can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/5894196