# How to make Javascript type a month's name?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDate').datepicker();
        });

        function getdate() {
            var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;

            var date = new Date(tt);
            var newdate = new Date(date);
            //Second Date
            newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);

            var dd = newdate.getDate();
            var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
            var y = newdate.getFullYear();

            var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
            document.getElementById('second_date').value = someFormattedDate;

            //Third Date
            newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);

            var dd = newdate.getDate();
            var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
            var y = newdate.getFullYear();

            var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
            document.getElementById('third_date').value = someFormattedDate;
          }
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
            background: #fff;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 5px auto 0;
            font: 10pt Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid #b4b3b3;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Date:
    <input id="txtDate" type="text" />


    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow Date" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Follow Date:
    <p>
        2nd day:
    <input id="second_date" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        3rd day:
    <input id="third_date" type="text" />
    </p>
```

I have the above code and I was wondering if you have any clue how I can make it type the name of the month, not just the number?

P.S. I am a total newbie and I know you're all advanced, but tried to figure it out and I couldn't.

EDIT: Saw the question here: [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date) but can't quite figure out how to add it in this scenario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy'});
        });

        function getdate() {
            var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;

            var date = new Date(tt);
            var newdate = new Date(date);
            //Second Date
            newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);

           
           document.getElementById('second_date').value = newdate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {  
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'short',
    year : 'numeric'
}).split(' ').join('/');

            //Third Date
            newdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);


            document.getElementById('third_date').value = newdate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {  
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'short',
    year : 'numeric'
}).split(' ').join('/');
          }
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
            background: #fff;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 5px auto 0;
            font: 10pt Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid #b4b3b3;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Date:
    <input id="txtDate" type="text" />


    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow Date" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Follow Date:
    <p>
        2nd day:
    <input id="second_date" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        3rd day:
    <input id="third_date" type="text" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just creating an array of (localized) names:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', ... etc];
```

Then just index it where needed:

```
var currentMonth = months[new Date().getMonth()];
```

Otherwise you might look at a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
               "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var selectedMonthName = months[$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()];
```

Comment: Could you possibly show me where should this go? I tested it locally and the whole thing just stopped.... Can you do it here?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5uv3b5hr/