# Strange behaviour of array - can't understand why

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a beginner in JS and just trying to understand what is going on in below code. Probably it's something stupid but - well, like I sayed, Im a beginner ;)

First it just split array which is an argument of `makeFriendlyDates(['2016-07-01', '2016-08-04']);` function.

So, at this stage everything is looking ok. However when I call `function changeToFriendly(arr1);` which only reason to exist is changing numbers into month name it somehow changes `newArr` as well.

So if I comment out this line: `//changeToFriendly(newArr);` then `newArr` is what is should be, but if the `changeToFriendly(newArr);` is called out it somehow changes `newArr` instead of just returning month name.

My question is how `changeToFriendly(newArr);` can change `newArr` if the function doesn't do anything with the array, just traversing it and checking number corresponding with month name.

```js
function makeFriendlyDates(arr) {
  var newArr = [];
  var elem;
  for (elem in arr) {
    newArr.push(arr[elem].split('-'));
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = newArr;

  function changeToFriendly(arr1) {
    var month = '';
    var elem1;
    for (elem1 in arr1) {
      if (arr1[elem1][1] = '01') {
        month = 'January';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '02') {
        month = 'February';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '03') {
        month = 'March';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '04') {
        month = 'April';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '05') {
        month = 'May';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '06') {
        month = 'June';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '07') {
        month = 'July';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '08') {
        month = 'August';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '09') {
        month = 'September';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '10') {
        month = 'October';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '11') {
        month = 'November';
      } else if (arr1[elem1][1] === '12') {
        month = 'December';
      }

    }
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = newArr;
    return month;
  }

  changeToFriendly(newArr);
}
makeFriendlyDates(['2016-07-01', '2016-08-04']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="result"></p>
  <p id="result1"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `for..in` is for looping objects, not arrays; you want a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Isn't array an object as well?

Comment: This is a very easy mistake to make.  `for...in` is almost deceptive in its meaning.

Comment: There's a typo on `if (arr1[elem1][1] = '01') {` it should be `===`

Comment: you could use the number of a month as index for an array with the month names.

Comment: TomSki, `for...in` loops across an objects *keys*.  An array doesn't store its items by key.

Comment: Well, it is an object, but you want to loop it as an array, meaning you want to loop numeric indices, not unordered key-value pairs.

Comment: @elclanrs - that's silly:  `var a = [3, 4]; for(i in a) { console.log(a[i]); }`

Comment: @4castle Thanks, it looks like we have a culprit :)

Comment: @elclanrs or [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: @Madbreaks, don't think that's silly, it's the intent of the iteration that confuses people, and that's why thinking about it in those terms makes sense.

Comment: @elclanrs no I mean, it's silly to state that `for..in` is to blame here, or that it can't be used on arrays.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: Unless you're specifically trying to implement/practice arrays or loops, it might be worth looking into the `Date` object for this sort of logic. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Madbreaks, I didn't say it was to blame, hence the comment, nor I did say it wasn't possible to use it with arrays, but that it is not meant to be used to loop arrays (as in the concept of an array of contiguous numeric indices).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is likely the single `=` here:

```
for (elem1 in arr1) {
      if (arr1[elem1][1] = '01') {
                        ^^^
```

...which means your `if` always evaluates to true.

Comment: You should know not to answer typo questions. Close it instead

Comment: It may be a typo, but the explanation of _why_ that results in the behavior seen is worthwhile IMO.

Comment: @4castle Yes, you are right about the typo, but I still don't understand how it changes newArr?

Comment: @TomSki Assignment statements change arrays. Comparison statements do not

Comment: @Madbreaks The explanation of why should be done in a comment, not an answer. If the typo really was obscure, I would understand answering.

Comment: Thanks again @4castle

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
function makeFriendlyDates (arr) {

  // Splits each element of the array, and returns an array of results
  var splitArr = arr.map(function (el) {return el.split('-');});

  // Prefer console.log to printing to HTML
  // document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = splitArr;
  console.log(splitArr);

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
    "November", "December"
  ];

  // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/1327983
  splitArr.forEach(function (el) {
    var month = monthNames[ parseInt(el[1])-1 ];
    // What do you want to do with it from here?
    el[1] = month;
  });

  // Demonstrate results
  console.log(splitArr);
}

makeFriendlyDates(['2016-07-01', '2016-08-04']);
```