# Formatting JSON date in Javascript rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, date

I am having trouble formatting a date from JSON from `2017-03-22 00:00:00 -0400` format to `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

```
var formatResults = function(data) {
      return "<tr>" +
                "<td data-title=\"amount\" class=\"amount\">" + data['amount'] + "<span class=\"result\">result</span></td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"case\">" + data['case'] + "</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"title\">Title of Case</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"user\" class=\"numeric\">" + data['person'] + "</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"location\" class=\"numeric\">" + data['office'] + "</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"date\" class=\"numeric\">" + data['date'] +
                "</td>" +
             "</tr>";
};
```

How can I transform the date passed directly from the JSON into the necessary format above?

Comment: `let [[year, mon, day]] = date.split(' ').map(s => s.split('-'));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @JaredSmith - can you provide an example of using your solution within my code?

Comment: You should use 'moment' here. And call it something like:
`moment('2017-03-22 00:00:00 -0400','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss -HH:mm').format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use  [`new Date(dateString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)  as long as the format can be parsed by [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```js
var date = new Date('2017-03-22 00:00:00 -0400');
var formattedDate = (date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate()+'/'+date.getFullYear();

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: `Date.parse` is implementation-dependent except for ISO 8601 formatted date strings, which this isn't.

Comment: Yeah, it should have used `Date.prototype.getDate` instead of `Date.prototype.getDay`

Comment: How can I change the month to the word (i.e., Jan) instead of 1 and so on?

Comment: For that you may have to use a third-party library like moment or something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to transpile the ES 6 for older browsers, but here you go:

```
var formatResults = function(data) {
      let [[year, mon, day]] = date.split(' ').map(s => s.split('-'));
      let date = `${mon}/${day}/${year}`;
      return "<tr>" +
                "<td data-title=\"amount\" class=\"amount\">" + data['amount'] + "<span class=\"result\">result</span></td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"case\">" + data['case'] + "</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"title\">Title of Case</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"user\" class=\"numeric\">" + data['person'] + "</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"location\" class=\"numeric\">" + data['office'] + "</td>" +
                "<td data-title=\"date\" class=\"numeric\">" + date +
                "</td>" +
             "</tr>";
};
```

Answer (score -1):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is perfect for this kind of thing.

Comment: Don't want to use an additional resource to format one date. Should be able to just use built in JS to do so.

Comment: Fair enough. You could try this: 

`var date = new Date('2017-03-22 00:00:00 -0400');
alert((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());`