# JavaScript currant date month format issue

Tags: javascript, html

Im try to do using `html` convert to full name of month but i cant correctly do that , anyone know how to do that i need to `21-September-2017` 
please help me to fix this 
thanks,

```js
function init(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var x = d.toDateString().substr(4, 3);
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    document.querySelector("#date").innerHTML = day + '-' + x + '-' + year;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/492258)

Comment: Well you have `toLocalizedString` nowadays.

Comment: Sir im used `html` and `java script`

Comment: Try this: `d.toLocaleString('en-GB',{month:'long'});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleString()` to get month.

```js
function init(){
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var locale = "en-us";
    var month = d.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    document.querySelector("#date").innerHTML = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Sir Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can not get full month name directly. But you can do a manual implementation like this,

```
var d = new Date();
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var n1 = month[d.getMonth()];
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var final_date = day+"-"+n1+"-"+year;
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b4qnskt5/)**

Comment: Sir Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

It converts your date to the locale format used by the language and country code specified. Only usable in up to date browsers.

```js
function init(){
    var d = new Date();
    var options = {day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' };
    document.querySelector("#date").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

> This will use the current time zone of the client. To negate this use these options:
>   `options.timeZone = 'UTC';`
>   `options.timeZoneName = 'short';`

Comment: Sir Thanks for the help