# Change dates to months in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array which look like this:

```
var myDates = ["2017-12-01 08:44:49", "2017-12-03 08:54:49", "2018-01-03 10:54:43"]
```

I want to create new array with name of Moth, ie.

```
var myMonths = [
    'December', 'March', 'January']
];
```

How i can achieve this?

I can do it on one string using something like this:

```
var oneMonth = "2017-12-01 08:44:49";
var str = oneMonth.substring(5,7);

var months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
    'October', 'November', 'December'
];

var saleMonths = months[str-1];
console.log(saleMonths);
```

Comment: parse the substring into a number, then search for the numbers -1 element in the months array. like this:

`var number = parseInt(str);
var my_month = months[number-1];`

Comment: Yes you can do it like the way you mentioned, except that you need to translate the substring to a number first, so that you can use it as array's index.

Comment: I believe your initial `myMonths` is incorrect.  Shouldn't it be `['December', 'December', 'January']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` and `substring` (**extending your own logic of `substring`**)

```
myMonths  = myDates.map( s => months[ +s.substring(5,7) - 1 ] );
```

```js
var myDates = ["2017-12-01 08:44:49", "2017-12-03 08:54:49", "2018-01-03 10:54:43"];
var months = [
  'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
  'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
  'October', 'November', 'December'
];
var myMonths  = myDates.map( s => months[ +s.substring(5,7) - 1 ] ); 

console.log( myMonths );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can map using `toLocaleString`

To add a bit more information:

"long" uses the full name of the month, "short" for the short name, and "narrow" for a more minimal version, such as the first letter in alphabetical languages.

You can change the locale to any that you please, and it will use the right name for that language/country.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648314/3483203) answer.

```js
var myDates = ["2017-12-01 08:44:49", "2017-12-03 08:54:49", "2018-01-03 10:54:43"]
const months = myDates.map(d => new Date(d).toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" }))
console.log(months)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should work for you.

Firstly you [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your dates and get each month. Then you map over these months and use the index to get the month as a word based on the `months` array.

```js
var myDates = ["2017-12-01 08:44:49", "2017-12-03 08:54:49", "2018-01-03 10:54:43"]

var months = [
  'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
  'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
  'October', 'November', 'December'
];

let monthWords = myDates.map(month => {
  return month.substring(5, 7);
}).map(item => {
  return months[parseInt(item) - 1]
});

console.log(monthWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you do to one string to all the strings in the array.

An easy way of doing that will be using the `map` function. Here is an example:

```js
var myDates = ["2017-12-01 08:44:49", "2017-12-03 08:54:49", "2018-01-03 10:54:43"];
var months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
    'October', 'November', 'December'
];

var onlyMonths = myDates.map(date => {
    var monthIndex = date.substr(5, 2) - 1;
    return months[monthIndex];
});

console.log(onlyMonths)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the string `str` into a number, then search for the number -1 element in the months array. like this:

```
var oneMonth = "2017-12-01 08:44:49";
var number= parseInt(oneMonth.substring(5,7));

var months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
    'October', 'November', 'December'
];

var saleMonths = months[number-1];
console.log(saleMonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer used the `Date` object to parse the string and fetch the month.

Then it looks up what month to return from an array of month names.

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function toMonth(dateString) {
  var d = new Date(dateString);
  return months[d.getUTCMonth()];
}
//TEST
var myDates = ["2017-12-01 08:44:49", "2017-12-03 08:54:49", "2018-01-03 10:54:43"];
console.log(myDates.map(function(d) {
  return toMonth(d);
}));
```