# Javascript Remove Day Name from Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i wanted to ask if someone knows how to remove the Day Name from the following example,the alert returns Sat Feb 29 2020, im not using Moment.js only Jquery because i only need to be able to handle the date in the format that is written below as code.

```
var mydate = new Date('29 Feb 2020');
alert(mydate.toDateString());
```

Thank you for reading this question and hope i make clear what my problem is

Comment: just don't use `toDateString()` and format your date your own way because  that function always return that format

Comment: I had read about that but i dont really understand how to properly format dates in javascript, so i though that there could be a way to just cut out the day name, anyway thank you for answering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [`Date#toDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method would result always returns in that particular format.

So either you need to generate using other methods available or you can remove using several ways,

---

1. Using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var mydate = new Date('29 Feb 2020');
// split  based on whitespace, then get except the first element
// and then join again
alert(mydate.toDateString().split(' ').slice(1).join(' '));
```

---

2. Using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var mydate = new Date('29 Feb 2020');
// replace first nonspace combination along with whitespace
alert(mydate.toDateString().replace(/^\S+\s/,''));
```

---

3. Using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```js
var mydate = new Date('29 Feb 2020');
// get index of first whitespace
var str = mydate.toDateString();
// get substring
alert(str.substr(str.indexOf(' ') + 1));
```

Comment: All of them work! A big Thank you for answering so fast!

Answer (score 4):

Proper way is to use DateTimeFormat. You can play around by manipulating the format object inside DateTimeFormat.

```js
let myDate = new Date('29 Feb 2020');
let formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "short",
  day: "2-digit",
}).format(myDate);

alert(formattedDate)
```

Comment: That's the simplest and best way.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a Date object instance and only want some parts of it I'd go with the [Date object API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
mydate.getDate() + ' ' + mydate.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: "short" }) + ' ' + mydate.getFullYear()
```

Just keep in mind the functions are local time based (there are UTC variants, e.g. `getUTCDate()`), also to prevent some confusion `getMonth()` is zero-based. Working with dates in JavaScript is where the real fun begins ;)

The [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) function is relatively new though (IE11+), check [other possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date) if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: So thats how you manually create a Date with the Javascript API? Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, it's always good to know you can format a date from its parts instead of fiddling with outputs of predefined-format functions (`toDateString`, `toISOString`) or using an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to replace all alpha characters from a string. That way you will not make mistake once day name is in a different position.

```js
var withoutDay = '29 Feb 2020'.replace(/[a-zA-Z]{0,1}/g,'').replace('  ', ' ');
alert(withoutDay);
```

Code `replace(/[a-zA-Z]{0,1}/g,'')` will replace all alpha characters from string and `replace('  ', ' ');` will remove double spaces.

I hope this helps.