# How to get the full date with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the full date with my function. Right now my results are "Wed Feb 14 2018", but I would like it to say "Wednesday February 2018". I want it to say the whole day and whole month. I could not find a "get fullDate" method unfortunately..

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();

  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toDateString();
}
```

```html
<div id="date"> </div>
```

Comment: @GordonKushner thanks! used it before, but does not work. When using that, I get the timestamp aswell with the Wed Feb 14 2018

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Answer (score 8):

You're actually looking for the `toLocaleString` function, [as it can be customized pretty heavily without losing your date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Syntax).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();

  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {weekday: 'long', month: 'long', year: 'numeric'});
}
```

```html
<div id="date"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for native date methods:

```js
function dateConvert(){
      let date = new Date();
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      let month= date.getMonth();
      let day = date.getDay();
  
      let months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
      let days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  
      return converted_date = `${days[day]} ${months[month]}  ${year}`;
    }
    
document.write(dateConvert());
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, the native [Date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) are a bit limited. There are a handful of roll-your-own approaches and if this is all you need then that is probably what you should use. If you need something more robust I would recommend a library to avoid running over many pitfalls in attempting to handle the craziness of formatting time correctly.

A very popular library is called [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). A very simple solution for your issue is to use their [`format` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```js
const date = new Date();

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = moment().format("dddd MMMM YYYY");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="date"> </div>
```

Hope this helps!