# how to get all months between the 2 dates present in String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, loops, date

i have a string as **Date between March 2018 and June 2018**. 
Now i am getting march 2018 and June 2018 in 2 variables.Now i want o/p as

> March 2018 
>  April 2018 
>  May 2018 
>  June 2018

CODE:

```
var temp="Date between March 2018 and June 2018";
var fields=temp.split(' ');
var date2=fields[fields.length-2] +" "+fields[fields.length-1];

var date1=fields[fields.length-5] +" "+fields[fields.length-4];
alert(date1);//March 2018
alert(date2);//June 2018
```

Comment: You can simply use for loop to find range between your months, `for(var i = new Date(date1).getMonth() + 1; i < new Date(date2).getMonth();i++) {
    console.log(i)
}`. Then you can map `var i` to `month name` by defining `months` as array

Comment: If you don't use a plugin, you'll need an array of month names.  Here's an example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date  use that with `indexOf` to get the two month positions, then extrapolate.

Comment: @sriharsha_bhat i am getting as 3,4 as the  o/p not the o/p i want Month name along with yr

Comment: @Shrey I added updated code in answer

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ while guidance has been given and mostly-complete answers provided, these should be expanded by OP to get their final solution.  Instead OP is just adding new details to valid answers such as "need in an array" (not in the question) or "also need extremities" (not in question and the opposite of "between").  These do not affect the validity of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the names of months between the two months in the `string`:

- You first need to declare an `array` with the names of all `months` sorted.
- Extract the two months from your `string`.
- Get the `indexes` of your two `months` in the `array` of months.
- Loop through the `array` between the two `indexes` and get the months.

This is how should be the code:

```
var temp = "Date between March 2017 and June 2018";
var dateStrings = temp.match(/(\w+\s\d{4})/gi);

const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
let index1 = monthNames.indexOf(dateStrings[0].split(" ")[0]);
let index2 = monthNames.indexOf(dateStrings[1].split(" ")[0]);
let year1 = dateStrings[0].split(" ")[1];
let year2 = dateStrings[1].split(" ")[1];

var diff = +year2 - +year1;
var results = [];
if (diff == 0) {
  for (var i = index1; i <= index2; i++) {
    results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year1);
  }
} else {
  for (var i = index1; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
    results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year1);
  }
  diff--;
  var year = +year1 + 1;
  for (var y = 0; y < diff; y++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
      results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year);
    }
    year++;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= index2; i++) {
    results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year2);
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var temp = "Date between March 2016 and June 2018";
var dateStrings = temp.match(/(\w+\s\d{4})/gi);


const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

let index1 = monthNames.indexOf(dateStrings[0].split(" ")[0]);
let index2 = monthNames.indexOf(dateStrings[1].split(" ")[0]);

let year1 = dateStrings[0].split(" ")[1];
let year2 = dateStrings[1].split(" ")[1];

console.log(+year2 - +year1);

var diff = +year2 - +year1;
var results = [];
if (diff == 0) {
  for (var i = index1; i <= index2; i++) {
    results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year1);
  }
} else {
  for (var i = index1; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
    results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year1);
  }
  diff--;
  var year = +year1 + 1;
  for (var y = 0; y < diff; y++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
      results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year);
    }
    year++;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= index2; i++) {
    results.push(monthNames[i] + " " + year2);
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: not worked if i changed the string to Date between January 2017 and December 2018

Comment: Well, you should have said that from the beginning.We need to edit the code.

Comment: sir could u pls include Months start and End in the O/p

Comment: It's done, however it's not too complicate to do that, and you did not mentioned that in your question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for this:

```
const numberOfMonthsDiff = moment(date2).diff(moment(date1), 'months', true);
```

[Documentation of the diff method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

> By default, moment#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal
>   places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number,
>   pass true as the third argument. Before 2.0.0, moment#diff returned a
>   number rounded to the nearest integer, not a truncated number.

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bjgv0rp4/)

**Edit**

I understand you want the months between:

```
var temp="Date between March 2018 and June 2018";
var fields=temp.split(' ');
var date2=fields[fields.length-2] +" "+fields[fields.length-1];
var date1=fields[fields.length-5] +" "+fields[fields.length-4];
const numberOfMonthsDiff = moment(date2).diff(moment(date1), 'months', true);

const dateToModify = moment(date1);
const monthsBetween = Array.from(Array(numberOfMonthsDiff)).map(i => dateToModify.add(1,'months').format('MMMM YYYY'));
```

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sL1grac3/)

Comment: sir i don't want the Difference between the 2 months i want the Months name with yr between them

Comment: No i want an array in which i will have all the values

Comment: can we get March also in the o/p ?

Comment: There's nothing in the question about returning an array - you must update your question with all the information, rather than add comments to individual answers.

Answer (score 1):

maybe we need to take years into consideration too. :-) https://jsfiddle.net/z07rwmnL/17/

```
var months = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
]

var temp = "Date between March 2018 and June 2019";
var match = temp.match(/Date between (\S+) (\d+) and (\S+) (\d+)/);

if (match) {
  var fromMonth = match[1];
  var fromYear = parseInt(match[2], 10);
  var toMonth = match[3];
  var toYear = parseInt(match[4], 10);

  if (toYear >= fromYear) {
    var fromMonthIdx = months.indexOf(fromMonth);
    var toMonthIdx = months.indexOf(toMonth);

    while (toYear >= fromYear) {
      var endIdx = (toYear > fromYear) ? 12 : toMonthIdx;
      for (var i = fromMonthIdx + 1; i < endIdx; i++) {
        console.log(months[i] + " " + fromYear);
      }
      fromMonthIdx = -1;
      fromYear++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have it here https://jsfiddle.net/o5uL6tgp/ if you want to test. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use for loop for getting range in between months,

```js
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
                       "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
                       var temp="Date between March 2018 and June 2018";
var fields=temp.split(' ');
var date2=fields[fields.length-2] +" "+fields[fields.length-1];

var date1=fields[fields.length-5] +" "+fields[fields.length-4];
for(var i = new Date(date1).getMonth(); i <= new Date(date2).getMonth();i++) {
    console.log(monthNames[i])
}
```

Comment: how to get march and June also in the o/p

Comment: @Shrey you **really** need to do *some* work yourself.  Just remove the `+1` and change `i <` to `i <=`.  However your question was months *between* where between does not include the limits (as they are not "between").

Comment: sir i am not getting yr here

Comment: @Shrey I changed the condition in for loop, Basically I removed +1 so it starts from `date1` and I put `<=` instead of `<` so it will loop till `date2`. This should give solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use regular expression to find two date boundary, and then loop through it for the expected output. Note that this solution cater cross year (no exception handling, it assumed your input string is in **constant** format).

```
var str = "Date between March 2017 and June 2018"; 
var startRE =  /between (.*) and/g;
var endRE =  /and (.*)/g;
var start = startRE.exec(str);
var end = endRE.exec(str);
var startDate = start[1]
var endDate = end[1]

var startMonth = startDate.split(' ')[0]
var startYear = startDate.split(' ')[1]

const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var endMonth = endDate.split(' ')[0];
var endYear = endDate.split(' ')[1];
for(var y=startYear;y<=endYear; y++){
    if(y==endYear){
        if(startYear==endYear)
          for(var m=monthNames.indexOf(startMonth);m<monthNames.indexOf(endMonth)-1;m++){
              console.log("Output:"+monthNames[m] + " " + y);
          }
        else
          for(var m=0;m<monthNames.indexOf(endMonth);m++){
              console.log("Output:"+monthNames[m] + " " + y);
          }
    }
    else{
        if(y=startYear)
        for(var m=monthNames.indexOf(startMonth);m<12;m++){
          console.log("Output:"+monthNames[m] + " " + y);
        }
        else
        {
          for(var m=0;m<12;m++){
            console.log("Output:"+monthNames[m] + " " + y);
          }
        }
    }
}
```