# Reading data from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an ionic app, which I would like to integrate with firebase. I have the following code in my **home.ts file**:

```
export class HomePage {
  UHSGetMonths$: Observable < any[] > ;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public platform: Platform,
    private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation,
    private UHSMonths: UHSGetMonthsService,
    public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
    private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.platform.ready().then((ready) => {
      this.localNotifications.on('tap', (notification, state) => {
        let json = JSON.parse(notification.data);

        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: notification.title,
          subTitle: json.fullMsq
        });
        alert.present();
      });
    });

    //this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);

    this.UHSGetMonths$ = this.UHSMonths
      .getUHSMonthsList() // DB LIST
      .snapshotChanges() // Give access to both Key and Value
      .map(changes => {

        return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key,
          ...c.payload.val(),
        }));
      });
  }
}
```

I can successfully retrieve the data in my template files but how do get access a value in firebase database from the `home.ts`? In Firebase, I have  meeting names and times for each month. E.g. for July, the team briefing takes place at 10am. How can I get the value 10am to use and manipulate in my `home.ts`?

Thanks

Firebase JSON file snippet:

`[ {
  "days" : [ {
    "StaffBriefing" : "10:00",
    "Team A Meeting" : "11:30",
    "Team B Meeting" : "13:00",
    "Team C Meeting" : "15:30",
    "Date" : "01"
  }, {
    "StaffBriefing" : "14:00",
    "Team A Meeting" : "12:45",
    "Team B Meeting" : "14:00",
    "Team C Meeting" : "16:30",
    "Date" : "02"
  }, {
    "StaffBriefing" : "09:00",
    "Team A Meeting" : "14:00",
    "Team B Meeting" : "11:00",
    "Team C Meeting" : "15:30",
    "Date" : "03"
  } ],
  "monthName" : "January"
} ]`

**Update - 03/08/2018**

Yes, I added the subscription code after the `this.UHSGetMonths$`. However, the following code worked:

```
`this.JubileeMonths
  .getJubileeMonthsList() // DB LIST
  .valueChanges()
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
 });`
```

And the `console.log(data)` displays:

[image]

If I do **console.log(data[0]);** I get this, which is fine.

[image]

However, If I try doing **console.log(data[0].monthName);** I get an error in my code editor (Atom) i.e. **Property 'monthName' does not exist on type '{}'` but in the console I get the correct value of January.

[image]

Why the error in the code editor or am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks.

**UHSGetMonthsService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as moment from 'moment';

    @Injectable()
    export class UHSGetMonthsService {
    private UHSGetMonthsRef$ = this.fbDB.list('UHS/Calendar/months');

      constructor(private fbDB: AngularFireDatabase) {

      }

      getUHSMonthsList() {
        return this.UHSGetMonthsRef$;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)?

Comment: Yes, I've had a look at docs and youtube tutorials but can't seem to understand how to do this.

Comment: What part is confusing you? The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) are pretty straightforward when it comes to explaining how to read data.

Comment: Well, I pretty new to Firebase. May be an example on how to retrieve data from within home.ts would help. As mentioned, I can retrieve data from template files just can't figure out how to access a value using a key. I understand that .snapshotChanges() gives me access to both Key and Value but how do I use this with the home.ts file? Thanks

Comment: `snapshotChanges()` is for an `AngularFirestoreCollection` which is a part of angularfire2. I thought you were asking how to get data with firebase, my apologies.

Comment: I've added a snippet of the JSON from Firebase. From my home.ts file, I would like to access for example the `Team C` meeting time for `Date 2` object.

Comment: What does `UHSGetMonthsService` look like?

Comment: I've updated the post with `UHSGetMonthsService ` code.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I tired the updated code but still getting the same error: **Property 'days' does not exist on type '{}'**. Strange...

Comment: Try putting the interface on the subscription's return value as well. `.subscribe((data: Month[]) => {`. You'll have to import `Month` from `UHSGetMonthsService`. Speaking of which, why do you have an entire service just to return a simple list reference?

Comment: That worked! thank you so much. The service will return additional stuff at later date. Just keeping it simple for now, until I get this issue sorted. Many thanks.

Comment: I recommend storing your interfaces in a single directory, each in their own file to keep them organized so you'll always know where to import them from.

Answer (score 1):

Given your database structure, you could do this after `UHSGetMonths$` is set:

```
this.UHSGetMonths$
  .subscribe(months => {
    if (months && months.length) {
      let month = months.find(m => m.monthName === 'January');
      let day = month.days.find(d => d.Date === '02');
      console.log(day['Team C Meeting']);
    }
  });
```

If you wanted to get the current month's name for the `.find()`, you'd need to either use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/2305594)'s solution or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).
If you wanted to get the current day of the month, you can use `new Date().getDate()` or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) again.

**Update:**

You're getting the error because you haven't defined the "shape" of the return data, so as far as your IDE knows, it's just a generic object. To fix this, create an interface that matches what the data looks like and use it on your list reference.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export interface Month {
  monthName: string;
  days: any[];
}

@Injectable()
export class UHSGetMonthsService {
private UHSGetMonthsRef = this.fbDB.list<Month>('UHS/Calendar/months');

  constructor(private fbDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getUHSMonthsList() {
    return this.UHSGetMonthsRef;
  }
}
```

Comment: With this I get: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. Just wondering, If `snapshotChanges()` gives access to both Key and Value then how can I use the key to retrieve its value?

Comment: Did you add the subscription code _after_ the code where you set `this.UHSGetMonths$` to an Observable? The key and value are both returned at the same time with `.snapshotChanges()`, you don't need to re-query for it, that would be redundant.

Comment: I have edited my post with additional details. Please see the part: **Update - 03/08/2018**. Thanks for your assistance, its appreciated.