# Access Component props from third party component - vuejs datepicker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-datepicker

Any ideas to access this Datepicker prop > PickerMonth > pageDate
The idea is, I want to get the month name when @changedMonth is triggered.

```html
<datepicker 
  :inline="true" 
  v-model="dateState" 
  :disabledDates="disabledDates"
  :highlighted="highlighted"
  @changedMonth="changedMonth"></datepicker>
```

```js
changedMonth(value) {
  console.log(Datepicker> PickerMonth> pageDate) //which is Fri Feb 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 as an example
}
```

Comment: instead of using a hacky solution, you would be better off using stable solution like https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs or momentjs, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/5599288

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `value` passed to your method? Looking at the source code of `vuejs-datepicker`, that should contain information on the selected month

Comment: @Phil yes you're right

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this component as a date picker, https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker, then `changedMonth` event handler will provide your the required changed month as input (Use `$event`).

Comment: No need to use `$event`, OP already has the event payload in `value`