# How to Extract Months from dates contains in a html table column?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table. One column contains date values. I want to extract `month` of those `dates` and print it in the console. Date format is **yyyy-MM-dd**. Here is my code:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('openDispatchNoteTable');

for (var i = 0 ; i < myTable.rows.length ; i++) {
    console.log("date : " + myTable.rows[i].cells[6].innerText);
}
```

`myTable.rows[i].cells[6].innerText` gives `2018-November-14` as the output.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if format is the same in all of outputs - then use regexp `.innerText.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0]`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerText.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0])
```

```html
<div>2018-November-14</div>
```

Also i found good internationalized solution here: [get month name from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date) Second best answer uses `toLocaleString`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use the **replace()** method of Javascript.

Use this `replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")` regex which will replace everything with "" other then characters.

```js
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = 1; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
  console.log("Actual Date : " + myTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerText);
  console.log("Only Month : " + myTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      28-November-2018
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      29-November-2018
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      30-November-2018
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/). It has a very elaborate API to handle things just like your need. In this case, the moment object can get the date in your format and then you can use the `month` function to extract the month.