# Locale 'default' is not well-formed

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

The following piece of code gets the month from a `date` object in JavaScript.

```
const date = new Date(dateValue);
const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
```

For example: if the date is something like `30/07/2019` it will return `Nov`.

This works fine in Chrome but fails in Edge browser with error:

> SCRIPT5121: SCRIPT5121: Locale 'default' is not well-formed

My Edge browser version is 41.16299.1004.0

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dwcv9xu/1

As per MDN, `date.toLocaleString` is fully supported in Edge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility.

Also I couldn't find this error code in the MSDN docs for Edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/error-and-status-codes.

Is there a way to fix this or any alternate approach to get the month in `mmm` format?

Comment: It's working fine for me in Edge 44.17763.1.0

Comment: is this relevant? https://github.com/hiddentao/fast-levenshtein/issues/17

Answer (score 3):

As per the suggestion from Phuzi, i changed to

```
date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: 'short' })
```

then it started working in IE 11 But it doesn't work in IE 10. 
So i went with Classic Javascript approach

Answer (score 3):

Might seem crazy, but using `undefined` rather than `default` resolves the error in IE11 and works in all the major browsers that I've checked (Mac/Windows).

```
const date = new Date(dateValue);
const month = date.toLocaleString(undefined, { month: 'short' });
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments `locales` and `options` are not supported by all browser versions. Newer versions of Edge already support the `"default"` value, but older versions do not (despite supporting the parameters). I am not sure which version started to support the `"default"` value.

According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation), "if the locales argument is not provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used". Thus you could try `date.toLocaleString(undefined, { month: 'short' });`. Such value is supported by Edge.

The topic requires some more research. I stopped now once you answered the question with another solution. But if you have some more time give a try and share back your results with us.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this for completeness.

**In order to use the default locale with the `options` param, you should always pass an empty array or `undefined` to the `locales` parameter.**

The `locales` param for [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#parameters) follows [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#parameters). From MDN:

> To use the browser's default locale, pass an empty array

Passing `undefined` [will have the same effect as using an empty array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locale_identification_and_negotiation).

Passing the string "default" works in most modern browsers, but so will "defaul" or any invalid locale. This is because most
browsers will fall back on the default locale if they can't resolve it; this is not guaranteed to work and should not be expected to work, since it's incorrect usage.

Additionally, the `options` param is ignored entirely in older browsers, but the `locales` param will still be parsed correctly if both are used.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find a solution to the problem I have used an alternate approach which probably will work in all browsers:

```
const date = new Date(dateValue);
//const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];
const month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
```

Credits: [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Comment: One of the advantages of using `toLocaleDateString` is the localised names. Your solution is essentially the same as `date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: 'short' })` or `date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short' })`

Comment: @phuzi I tried your approach but it only returns some digits like: 1,564,484,065,517

Comment: I can see that you are using Edge 41. Which is older version. If possible for you than you can update with the latest version of Edge will solve your issue and your code is  working fine with the latest version of MS Edge.