# Why isn't this switch statement returning the current month?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm having trouble understanding why this switch statement isn't returning the value of October. I run the snippet and it's returning September.

```js
var monthOfYear = new Date().getMonth();

switch (monthOfYear) {
  case 1:
    month = 'January';
    break;    
  case 2:
    month = 'February';
    break;    
  case 3:
    month = 'March';
    break;    
  case 4:
    month = 'April';
    break;    
  case 5:
    month = 'May';
    break;    
  case 6:
    month = 'June';
    break;    
  case 7:
    month = "July";
    break;
  case 8:
    month = "August";
    break;
  case 9:
    month = "September";
    break;
  case 10:
    month = "October";
    break;
  case 11:
    month = "November";
    break;
  case 12:
    month = 'December';
    break;    
  default:
    month = "That's not a real month.";
}

outputVal.innerHTML = month;
```

```html
<h3 id="outputVal"></h3>
```

Comment: because 0 === january .... 11 === december

Comment: Yes, month are counted 0 to 11, so change all your inputs to the same value -1.

Comment: Unrelated: Maybe get yourself inspired by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643468/982149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

> The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date
>   according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates
>   the first month of the year).