# How to change the number format to letters the months in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
const getCurrentDate = () => {
  var date = new Date().getDate();
  var month = new Date().getMonth();

  return date + "-" + month;
};
```

I want to transform the number on the month var to letters f.e " 2-8  to 2 - August "

Comment: Try to use moment.js or if the example is simple store the months in array then refer to them using the month index

Comment: Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date

Answer (score 0):

Create a const-array for the months and get the month-th element of it.

```js
const MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

const getCurrentDate = () => {
  var date = new Date().getDate();
  var month = new Date().getMonth();

  return date + "-" + MONTHS[month];
};

console.log(getCurrentDate());
```

Comment: i fixed with :                                                                                                                                 const getCurrentDate = () => {
      var options = {
        weekday: "long",
        month: "short",
        day: "numeric",
      };
      var prnDt = new Date().toLocaleDateString("es", options);

      return prnDt;